# Prometheus filtering when using a recording rule

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have the following recording rule set up in Prometheus:

```
- record: web:prod:inbound_request_duration_seconds:by_private_ip:rate1m
  expr: sum(rate(inbound_http_request_duration_seconds_sum{job="prod-web"}[1m])) by (private_ip)
```

And when I execute the query by specifying the rule name in Grafana (or Prometheus Explorer) the recording rule works just fine.

What I want to do is filter that recording rule by `httpStatus` which I am sending in the Histogram set up in my app.

If I run do something like this:

```
web:prod:inbound_request_duration_seconds:by_private_ip:rate1m{httpStatus="^5..$"}
```

I don't get an error, I just get no output, whereas if I take the raw query and do this:

```
sum(rate(inbound_http_request_duration_seconds_sum{job="prod-web", httpStatus="^5..$"}[1m])) by (private_ip)
```

I get the output I am expecting.

**Is** it possible to filter on a recording rule? Or do I have to create additional recording rules with the filters I want included?

Answer (score 1):

Your recording rule aggregates all time series by `private_ip` and all other labels are removed. Use the following expression:

`sum(rate(inbound_http_request_duration_seconds_sum{job="prod-web"}[1m])) by (private_ip, httpStatus)`